# SQL - Two request that don't return me the same result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been in trouble using SQL. 
I've got a table named "PAYER" in which I want to get the count of distinct "NUMERO_REGLEMENT" where "NUMERO_PAIEMENT" is 69, it's as simple as that.

[image]

I said simple? 
When the normal return would be 1, as I get here when using imbrication:

> SELECT COUNT( NUMERO_REGLEMENT ) AS TOTAL FROM (
>
> > SELECT DISTINCT NUMERO_REGLEMENT
> >
> > FROM PAYER
> >
> > WHERE NUMERO_PAIEMENT =69
>
> )TEST

I get 0 when using this other request :

> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NUMERO_REGLEMENT) AS TOTAL
>
> FROM PAYER
>
> WHERE NUMERO_PAIEMENT=69

Don't know why this two requests give me differents results.

Comment: What RDBMS and version?

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? According to w3c : COUNT(DISTINCT) works with ORACLE and Microsoft SQL Server, but not with Microsoft Access.

Comment: I'm using MySQL version 5.5.25a.

The strangest thing is that request :

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NUMERO_REGLEMENT) AS TOTAL
FROM PAYER
WHERE NUMERO_PAIEMENT=68

Return me "1" correctly

Comment: it's all about `distinct`

Comment: I get correct result on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f4ed/6). Are you sure you are using the same database for query? Same logged in user?

Comment: Same database and user, for sure. Keep don't understanding what's wrong